# How to use Horizontal Orientation in WP8 ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm using the following xaml code to display a list horizontally,

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="429" Margin="18,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="420" Height="80">
                            <TextBox x:Name="tbName" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="70" Background="Green" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

What I want exactly is:
 after the TextBlock crosses the width it should be placed in the next line (Typically it should be like how we write in a paper).
i.e . until we reach the end of the **StackPanel** we will append the **TextBox** horizontally, but after the end of the **StackPanel** is reached we will place the next **TextBox** in the next line).

How can i do it??

Answer (score 6):

try to add this code in your listBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

the oriention of items depends on ItemsPanel.

Comment: i have updated the question pls do have a look at it!

Comment: Oh, I see, add TextWrapping="Wrap" to your textBox

Comment: That will work if i am going to add text in a textBox, but i want to textBoxes as i said above in a list

Comment: changed the question, have a look at it!

Comment: Oh, you want to add textbox into stackpanel dynamic?

Comment: I guess you can try to do with sizeChanged method. I also have no more idea.Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the namespace:

```
xmlns:tlk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and there is how to use it:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <tlk:WrapPanel></tlk:WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

**Remember**
You must reference: `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll`