# "Invalid XAML" when define ItemsPanelTemplate for ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I'm trying to make a list scroll horizontally, so I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695053/how-to-use-horizontal-orientation-in-wp8-listbox), but then debug give me this error

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>      
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

.................

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding HomeAlbumList}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HorizontalListTemplate}"
    SelectionChanged="SSC_ChangeAlbum"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}"
/>
```

I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 update 4.

Thanks for any help :) .

Comment: Close that document, clean your solution and build it.  Check the output for errors.  If the application builds correctly and runs, ignore this error.  The xaml editor is famous for false errors.

Comment: @Will thanks, and also when I copy that itemspaneltemplate to an external ResourcesDictionary file, now it's work ! I also had many other problem with VS XAML editor :( Hope they'd fix theme in VS 2015.